# What is fastest way to determine numbers are within specific range of each other in Python?

Tags: python

I have list of numbers as follows -

```
L = [ 1430185458, 1430185456, 1430185245, 1430185246, 1430185001 ]
```

I am trying to determine which numbers are within range of "2" from each other. List will be in unsorted when I receive it.

If there are numbers within range of 2 from each other I have to return "1" at exact same position number was received in.

I was able to achieve desired result , however code is running very slow.  My approach involves sorting list, iterating it twice taking two pointers and comparing it successively. I will have millions of records coming as seperate lists.

Just trying to see what is best possible approach to address this problem.

Edit -  Apology as I was away for a while. List can have any number of elements in it ranging from 1 to n. Idea is to return either 0 or 1 in exact same position number was received.  I can not post actual code I implemented  but here is pseudo code.

a.  create new list as list of list with second part as 0 for each element. We assume that there are no numbers within range of 2 of each other.

```
    [[1430185458,0], [1430185456,0], [1430185245,0], [1430185246,0], [1430185001,0]]
```

b.  sort original list

c.  compare first element to second, second to third and so on until end of list is reached and whenever difference is less than or equal to 2 update corresponding second elements in step a to 1.

```
    [[1430185458,1], [1430185456,1], [1430185245,1], [1430185246,1], [1430185001,0]]
```

Comment: You might try posting your algorithm on Code Review instead.

Comment: Why do you need sorting? Why do you need pointers? Looks like all you need to do is populate an n x n matrix with the distances and check which values are < 2.

Comment: Use a binary search traversal basically.  You should create disjoint sets of values that are not within two digits of one another as  you're going along.  Divide up everything.  Once you verify that the middle of the array is more than 2 digits from the smallest value split the sequence in half etc.  Keep using this divide and conquer approach until every element (Except those that are two away) are in their own sets.  Keep a reverse sorted representation of the different sets or a max heap by length.

Comment: Can you elaborate one what you want the output to be? It would be very useful if you could paste your code, since it does do what you want. If you post it on Code Review, please link to it here.

Comment: This sounds a bit like a homework assignment.  There is an `O(n)` solution to this problem.

Comment: @Jason With millions of records it doesn't sound like a homework problem, especially since OP says they already have a solution but are hoping to improve it.

Comment: @JohnColeman It might not be, but I have had similar problems as assignments.  There is an `O(n)` solution though (actually more than one).  Think about how many potential numbers there are that are within the target range.

Comment: @Jason If the goal is to find all pairs of indices (i,j) where |a[i] - a[j]| <= 2 and n is the length of the list then (without further assumptions on the lists) wouldn't it be `O(n^2)`? If repetitions are allowed in the list then it is possible that *all* of the numbers are within 2 of each other -- in which case the output alone is quadratic in n. But OTOH, OP hasn't been clear about either assumptions or desired output.

Comment: @JohnColeman That wasn't how I read the requirement *return "1" at exact same position number was received in*.  Returning the combinations would potentially be `O(n^2)`.  If that were a requirement, it could be done after processing the array though, and in a fairly efficient manner.

Comment: Assuming the result is a 0/1 list where a 1 at the ith position means the there exists some other index j such that L[i] and L[j] are within 2 of each other, there is indeed a nominally O(n) algorithm. You don't need to sort (O(n log n)), you don't need to assume numbers are unique, and you don't need create a distance matrix (O(n^2)). By nominally, that assumes average case O(1) performance for a python dict. But someone could create a nightmare list L specially tailored for a dict-based approach that results in lots of hash collisions.

Comment: @Jason -  This is not homework assignment.  I appreciate your comment and contribution but do you think everyone here is posting class assignment ?   Your comment is very mean and part of reason I was very hesitant to post question to SO and why I visit SO less frequently than I used to.   
What I have posted as problem is actually subset of very complex problem.  If you have heard of hourglass implementation of Apache DataFu, then I am trying to solve something on similar lines while trying to build my own solution.

Comment: @GoldenPlatinum - Please clarify what *I have to return "1" at exact same position number was received in* means. Given the list `[2,4,5]`, are you supposed to modify this to be `[1,1,5]`, produce a new list `[1,1,0]`, or something else?

Comment: @GoldenPlatinum It's your choice to post here, but quality of the responses you get depends directly on the quality of the description of the problem.  You'll notice someone added two answers after you clarified the problem.  I also tried to give a hint as to what the `O(n)` solution was.

Comment: @GoldenPlatinum SO is a public forum.  I'd recommend you read through the comments on your post again.

Answer (score 2):

The goal is to be fast, so that presumably means an O(N) algorithm. Building an NxN difference matrix is O(N^2), so that's not good at all. Sorting is O(N*log(N)), so that's out, too. Assuming average case O(1) behavior for dictionary insert and lookup, the following is an O(N) algorithm. It rips through a list of a million random integers in a couple of seconds.

```
def in_range (numbers) :
    result = [0] * len(numbers)
    index = {}
    for idx, number in enumerate(numbers) :
        for offset in range(-2,3) :
            match_idx = index.get(number+offset)
            if match_idx is not None :
                result[match_idx] = result[idx] = 1 
        index[number] = idx 
    return result
```

**Update**

> I have to return "1" at exact same position number was received in.

The update to the question asks for a list of the form `[[1,1],[2,1],[5,0]]` given an input of `[1,2,5]`. I didn't do that. Instead, my code returns `[1,1,0]` given `[1,2,5]`. It's about 15% faster to produce that simple 0/1 list compared to the `[[value,in_range],...]` list. The desired list can easily be created using `zip`:

```
zip(numbers,in_range(numbers))        # Generator
list(zip(numbers,in_range(numbers)))  # List of (value,in_range) tuples
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you need (process() modifies the list L). Very likely it's still optimizable, though:

```
def process(L):
    s = [(v,k) for k,v in enumerate(L)]

    s.sort()

    j = 0
    for i,v_k in enumerate(s):
        v = v_k[0]

        while j < i and v-s[j][0]>2:
            j += 1

        while j < i:
            L[s[j][1]] = 1
            L[s[i][1]] = 1
            j += 1
```